# Synchronizing an audio file over network in Unet

Tags: audio, networking, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I have a gameObject "plane" that isn't controlled by the clients. it gets spawned with an audio source that plays a clip when the host clicks a certain button. i would like the sound to be heard by the clients, i tried using rpc but i can't seem to be able to send them.

i keep getting the error: Found no behaviour for incoming [ClientRpc:InvokeRpcRpc_SendSoundIDToServer] on plane (UnityEngine.GameObject),  the server and client should have the same NetworkBehaviour instances.

It's been driving me crazy for more than a day, i would really apreciate some help.

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(NetworkIdentity))]
public class SpoolUp : NetworkBehaviour
{
private AudioSource source;

public AudioClip[] clips;
public bool start;

void Start()
{
clips = Resources.LoadAll("Audio");
source = GetComponent();
source.playOnAwake = false;
}
public void Spool()
{
start = true;
if (isServer)
PlaySound(0);
}

public void PlaySound(int id)
{
if (id >= 0 && id < clips.Length)
{
RpcPlaySound(id);
}
}
[ClientRpc]
void RpcPlaySound(int id)
{
source.PlayOneShot(clips[id]);
}
```

PS: I also get the following warning: ClientRpc [ClientRpc:InvokeRpcRpcPlaySound] handler not found [netId=4]

Comment: Why do you want to send the actual invoke? You could send a bool to "startPlaying" and play it in each client.

Comment: you mean using a syncvar attribute ??

Comment: yes, is faster and you don't need to send the actual file.